# Sorting a model's collection every time after it has been retrieved from the database

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Product` and a `Tag` model. They are connected with a [many-to-many relation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).
When I get a collection of `Tag`, I want it to be sorted at any time. Because the sort algorithm is implemented in PHP, I can not do this on database-level.

My first attempt was to simply override the [newCollection()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a915bdb78a05a61b751096589270101380715545/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1123) method of `Model`:

```
// Tag.php
public function newCollection(array $models = []): Collection
{
    return parent::newCollection($models)->sortBy(fn(Tag $tag) => $tag->present()->name)->values();
}
```

That works. Unfortunately, `newCollection()` is always called twice when retrieving a `Tag` collection from the database:
First time: [Builder::hydrate()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a915bdb78a05a61b751096589270101380715545/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L313)
Second time: [Builder::get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a915bdb78a05a61b751096589270101380715545/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L527)

That's far away from efficient. So I made another attempt. Instead of overriding `newCollection()`, I've overridden the [newEloquentBuilder()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a915bdb78a05a61b751096589270101380715545/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L1102) method of `Model`:

```
// Tag.php
public function newEloquentBuilder($query): Builder
{
    return new class($query) extends Builder {
        public function get($columns = ['*'])
        {
            return parent::get($columns)->sortBy(fn(Tag $tag) => $tag->present()->name)->values();
        }
    };
}
```

Seems to work! But unfortunately, not every time. `$product->tags` won't use `Builder::get()`. It uses [BelongsToMany::get()](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a915bdb78a05a61b751096589270101380715545/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsToMany.php#L761).

**So here my question:** Is there an efficient way to modify a collection of a specific model after it has been retrieved from the database?

Comment: I don't think that there is a way. You can only do it manually every time when you get the collection and then `sortBy` with a callback or just try to implement that sort that you are using in the MySQL, that will be the best and fastest way to do it :P

Answer (score 0):

It's often a bad idea to modify the default behavior like this, and you often find yourself needing the original default behavior somewhere down the road. I think a much cleaner approach would be to add a second method to the model which retrieves the collection and then applies the sort method.

```
public function sortedTags(): Collection {
 return $this->tags->sortBy('tag.present.name');
}
```

You may need to eager load the relationships to optimize things.

All that said, this is a bad idea from a performance perspective. It loads all of the data and then loops through it to sort. If you can push the sorting/ordering into sql you will be better off in the long run, especially if the set of data in the Tags table is expected to grow with time. It certainly makes for a less clean query as you would probably need to add the joins in to get things working, and you might want to switch to query builder depending on the complexity.